# React-Navigation: aligning header to center

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am having trouble aligning my custom header to the middle of the header in a Stack Navigation.

This is my current view:

[image: Current view]

I would like to have the menu icon to the left and the title centered.

My current code for the **screenOptions** in the **StackNavigator** are

```
  headerStyle: {
    backgroundColor: "#a5ade8",
    height: 80
  },
  headerTintColor: "#383f42",
  headerTitleStyle: {
    fontFamily: "heebo-black",
    fontSize: 24
  }
```

My code in my **custom header** is:

```
return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <MaterialIcons
        name="menu"
        style={styles.icon}
        size={24}
        onPress={openDrawer}
      />
      <View>
        <Text style={styles.headerTitle}>{title}</Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex:1,
    height: "100%",
    flexDirection: "row",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",

  },
  headerTitle: {
    fontFamily: "heebo-black",
    fontSize: 24,
    color: "#383f42",
    letterSpacing: 1,
  },
  icon: {
    position: "absolute",
    left: 16
  }
});
```

I have set my width to 100% in my header, however it takes only takes the space of the text...

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried to use the `headerTitleAlign` option in `screenOptions`?

```
const HomeStackNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator
      initialRouteName="Reviews"
      screenOptions={{
        headerTitleAlign: "center"
      }}
    >
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Reviews"
        component={Home}
        options={{
          headerTitle: () => (
            <View style={styles.container}>
              <View>
                <Text style={styles.headerTitle}>Reviews App</Text>
              </View>
            </View>
          ),
          headerLeft: () => (
            <MaterialIcons name="menu" size={35} style={styles.icon} />
          )
        }}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    height: "100%",
    flexDirection: "row",
    alignItems: "center"
  },
  headerTitle: {
    fontSize: 24,
    color: "#383f42",
    letterSpacing: 1
  },
  icon: {
    marginLeft: 10
  }
});
```

Comment: I have tried that but the Material Icon will be centred as well...

Comment: @Migliore I have changed the original answer to include the icon

Answer (score 0):

try

```
textAlign:'center'
```

at the header title styles

Answer (score 0):

Can you see the example here in this [expo-snack](https://snack.expo.io/rJzXjU3LU) , there in place of icon ive used text and your header is aligned center. 
Hope it helps. feel free for doubts

Comment: Interesting that the example works well with the same code, I am guessing the problem is with the React-Navigation Stack Navigator Header